# Seeing Replacement Characters in App Engine Devserver Servlets

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, character-encoding, google-cloud-platform

I'm using [App Engine's Maven plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven-reference) to deploy a simple servlet:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet{

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/json");

    String output = "testing ¡ ¿  ñ testing";

    response.getOutputStream().println(output);
  }
}
```

This servlet outputs some text that includes special characters like `¡`, `¿`, and `ñ`.

I run a local development server: `mvn appengine:devserver`

And I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/test`. I see this:

```
testing � �  � testing
```

I gather that these are [replacement characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) and indicate that something is wrong with my encoding.

I've tried specifically setting the charset:

```
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

I've also tried:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I've confirmed that the browser is getting this character encoding in the headers of the response:

[image: devserver headers]

But I still see the replacement characters instead of the original special characters.

If I deploy to a live App Engine site, then it works fine and the original special characters are shown. I see that the live site has a `content-encoding` of `gzip`, but this might be a red herring:

[image: live App Engine headers]

I've tried this on both Windows and Linux, and I'm getting the same behavior on both.

**How do I set the encoding of my local development server so I can see the original special characters instead of the replacement characters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I needed to call `response.getWriter().println(output)` instead of `response.getOutputStream().println(output)`.

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) for `HttpServletResponse`:

- `getOutputStream()` returns a `ServletOutputStream` suitable for writing binary data in the response. The servlet container does not encode the binary data.
- `getWriter()` returns a `PrintWriter` object that can send character text to the client. The `PrintWriter` uses the character encoding returned by `getCharacterEncoding()`.